# How to edit cgi files nagios in particular

Tags: cgi, edit, nagios

i want to edit my nagios cgi files but the keep opening as bin files. Does anyone know how to edit them or has anyone edited it before (nagios).
The reason i want to edit it is i want one of the pages to show columns instead of three, i checked the css but its not there.
Regards

Comment: In some cases "Custom CGI Headers and Footers" Nagios feature may help you to achive the result. 
http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/cgiincludes.html

Answer (score 1):

Nagios config files are compiled into bin files.  If you want to edit them you need to download the source, edit that, and compile again. Suggesting to the developers that the number, order, and type of columns seen be read from a config file might prove useful for the future.